# Android: Use LogCat to find where app hangs

Tags: android, logcat

My app hangs when calling the takePicture method. It never returns. I opened up LogCat but it is completely empty with no entries at all. Is there a way I can figure out where internally the app is hanging?

Comment: tried with 'adb lolcat' in terminal ?

Comment: or if buffer is overloaded adb logcat -c

Comment: Try to open Device tab and do double-click on your one. After that go to lagCat and it should be ok.

Comment: @CharanPai Lol, I thought it was a funny typo but `adb lolcat` indeed works!

Comment: no its not typo, both lolcat and logcat works same :)

Comment: @DheerajV.S. i somewer read that its a sense of humor frm google :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens sometime that Logcat doesn't show anything.
to solve this

Go to `DDMS->Device -> select your Device or emulator`.

If it doesn't work Restarting adb or eclipse will surely help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite used to problem for me.

Most of the time, I run my application, I didnt get any logcat entries, even if the device is connected. Mostly in case of Motorola Milestone.

I found a way to solve this,

> Every time, I have to open the logcat stack, I have to select my device from the Devices tab.

`DDMS->Device` or select it from `Windows-> showView`

Answer (score 0):

in terminal go to android sdk folder then
`cd platform-tools`
then type `./adb logcat`
You ll sure get logcat output.
before that you can flush buffer by `adb logcat -c` so that you will get logcat output only from your app and also you can filter output by tag by using `adb logcat -s tag_name`

Comment: @Neurenor lolcat and logcat both are same, and for me typing lolcat is much easier and faster than logcat ;)